# Vectorize row-wise additions using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A = [1,2,3] and a B = zeros(3,5)

I want to add A[0] to the first row of B, [1] to the second row, etc.

In the end I need the following result:

B =

1 1 1 1 1

2 2 2 2 2

3 3 3 3 3

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.zeros((3,5))
```

Doing a + b is not possible since I get an error. I could do it using a for loop:

```
for i in range ( len(a) ):
    b[i] += a[i]
```

But this gets long the more constraints I add to the code.

Can we perform this using a numpy operation?

Comment: `b += a[:,None]`?

Comment: @Divakar oh nice and clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
In [53]: A = np.array([1,2,3])
In [54]: B = np.zeros((3,5))
In [55]: A = A[:, None]

In [56]: A
Out[56]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [57]: B
Out[57]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [58]: A + B
Out[58]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

For an integer array as result:

```
In [59]: np.asarray(A + B, dtype=np.int)
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Numpy` broadcast method.

```
a.reshape(1,-1).T+b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

If you want in `intergers` use this:

```
(a.reshape(1,-1).T+b).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```